# turn series of string data points into list

Tags: python, string, pandas, list, type-conversion

I have imported some data that looks like a list of items because of square brackets, but is really just strings.

I used Pandas `df['column name'].values.tolist()` to convert each row to a list:

```
[
"41885593, 'DNV GL Group AS', 'DNVGI', 'SNPC', '2nd Party Consultant', datetime.date(2017, 2, 28)",
 "48551738, 'Vigeo SAS', 'VIGEO', 'SNPC', '2nd Party Consultant', datetime.date(2017, 2, 28)",
 "50177826, 'Climate Bonds Initiative', 'CLIBON', 'TRPC', '3rd Party Certifier', datetime.date(2017, 2, 28)"
]
```

But each item within the list has remained a string. I need each covert so they are actually separate items within a list rather than just strings. If I use `list(item)` to convert to a list, it breaks it down to each character as part of the list.

so if it worked, i would have a list like:

```
mystuff = [
            "41885593, 'DNV GL Group AS', 'DNVGI', 'SNPC', '2nd Party Consultant', datetime.date(2017, 2, 28)", 
            "48551738, 'Vigeo SAS', 'VIGEO', 'SNPC', '2nd Party Consultant', datetime.date(2017, 2, 28)", 
            "50177826, 'Climate Bonds Initiative', 'CLIBON', 'TRPC', '3rd Party Certifier', datetime.date(2017, 2, 28)"
            ]
```

And if I ran a for loop over it:

```
for item in mystuff:
    print(item)
    print("*********")
```

The output would be:

```
41885593, 'DNV GL Group AS', 'DNVGI', 'SNPC', '2nd Party Consultant', datetime.date(2017, 2, 28)
*********
48551738, 'Vigeo SAS', 'VIGEO', 'SNPC', '2nd Party Consultant', datetime.date(2017, 2, 28)
*********
50177826, 'Climate Bonds Initiative', 'CLIBON', 'TRPC', '3rd Party Certifier', datetime.date(2017, 2, 28)
*********
```

Comment: The input and output look the same to me.

Comment: You're right. i need to run some conversions on this data once i can access each element as an item in a list. But right now, the whole thing appears to be one item in a list rather than 3 separate lists with one list. It looks like a list of items separated with double quotes, but for some reason is just one long string.

Comment: if you recreate using `pd.Series(mylist)` you would still see 3 rows.. what is the issue exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each item of your `mystuff` list is a `str` that represents comma-separated elements. 
Solution based on the `split` method of `str` :

```
mystuff = [x.split(', ') for x in mystuff]
```

If you want `mystuff`as a list of items :

```
mystuff = sum(map(lambda x: x.split(', '), mystuff), [])
```